# If $|H|=p$ then $H$ is normal.

Tags: group-theory

Assume that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

If $|G|=pn$ with $p$ be a prime and $p>n$. If $|H|=p$  then $H$ is normal.

Why $H$ is normal.? I know by theorem Sylow $G$ have normal subgroup.

A suggestion to show that $H$ is normal.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: One of the Sylow theorems says that if $m$ is the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$, then $m\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ and $m\mid n$. What must $m$ be if these two conditions are satisfied?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need Sylow. Assume $H$ is not normal, so there is a $ g \in G$ with $K=H^g \neq H$. By Lagrange $H \cap K=1$. So $|HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|}=p^2 \leq |G|=pn$. Hence $p \leq n$,  a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If $|G|=pn$ with $p>n$, in particular $n\nmid p$.

If $H\le G$ with $|H|=p$ then $H$ is a $p$-Sylow of $G$.

The number of $p$-Sylow of $G$ is $n_p(G)$, which, by Slow Thms is such that
$$
\bullet\;\; n_p(G)\equiv1 \;\;\mbox{mod}\;p\\
\bullet\;\; n_p(G)\;|\;[G:H]=n
$$
thus $n_p(G)=1+kp$ which, if $k\ge1$, is $>p>n$, thus by the second of the properties above, $k=0$, so $n_p(G)=1$.

Thus $H$ is the unique $p$-Sylow subgroup. But every couple of $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ are conjugate, thus $H^x=H\;\;\forall x\in G$, i.e. $H$ is normal in $G$.